# How to import a component from a nested module in core.module or shared.module

Tags: angular

I am working on a large app and will have several smaller modules inside of core.module which will need to export components of their own.

How can I export/import the components to other modules without the module being loaded multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest almost no components in the core module. It is suggested to put common components in a shared module. Keep the core module mostly services/guards/interceptors/auth/utilities. View https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule

Comment: as extra for op, take a look in https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#folders-by-feature-structure